# How to select all data but the last week in RMySQL with timestamp?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have this column "timestamp" in table A, and I want to select all data but the last week, here is my R code but an error pop up saying "Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "dbWriteTable", for signature "MySQLConnection", "data.frame", "character"", any help would be appreciated? THANK YOU.

```
fun <- function(con, dat.set, tbl.name) {

if (dbExistsTable(con, tbl.name)) {     
BFWeek = dbGetQuery(con, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM A",
"WHERE timestamp < timestampadd(day, -7, now())"))   
dbWriteTable(con, BFWeek, tbl.name, row.names=F, append=T);            

} else { 
dbWriteTable(con, tbl.name, dat.set, row.names=F, append=T); 
  }
} 

fun(conn_table, df, "A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the table has to come *before* the data frame you want to write to that table. In the `else` part of your code, you seem to have the order correct, but in the `if` part you have `BFWeek` before `tbl.name` where it should go after.

```
> showMethods("dbWriteTable")
Function: dbWriteTable (package DBI)
conn="MySQLConnection", name="character", value="character"
conn="MySQLConnection", name="character", value="data.frame"
```

This would have given you an idea as to which methods are available and which are not.